# Is it possible to integrate Apple and/or Firebase Push Notifications to a React Native/Expo app with managed work flow?

Tags: react-native, expo, apple-push-notifications, firebase-notifications

I have a React Native App that I have been working on in Expo's managed workflow. I have acquired a Push Notifications Token through my Apple Developer Account. Is it possible to integrate APN/FBN into my app while still on managed workflow? I would rather not eject yet.

Comment: see the documentation for push notifications in expo, which outlines how to use these services directly or expo's notification service that provides a convenient wrapper around them. https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/overview/

Comment: I thought these were just for push notifications run through Expo?

Comment: @MK_Pierce I have a production app with expo push notifications service working, you can use it without problems in your production apps

Comment: @chuysbz will they charge for production app?

Answer (score 5):

The Expo platform does not lock you into using Expo's application services, and the `expo-notifications` API is push-service agnostic (you can use it with any push notification service).

So you can use APN, or FCM with Expo without ejecting.

Read more about it on Expo Docs: [Sending Notifications with APNs & FCM](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/sending-notifications-custom/)

Comment: Yes, Expo makes it really easy to work with push APIs.

Comment: I appreciate this info. Thank you very much